# Keep input prompt at the botton of terminal?

Tags: python, input

i'm working on a server project in python using asyncio and websockets and i need to be able to do input from the server while other connections are running in the background and they all print stuff independent of each other and of the server. i need to figure out an input function that shows a persistent input prompt (something like: `enter input:` ) and all other prints go on top of the prompt without altering the prompt.

here is the code i got:

```
def user_input():
    while True:
        message = input("type in your message: ")
        print(f"you typed: {message}")

user_input()
```

but it prints this:

```
type in your message: asdasd
you typed: asdasd
type in your message: sdfsdf
you typed: sdfsdf
type in your message:
```

where as i need it to look like this:

```
you typed: asdasd
you typed: sdfsdf
type in your message:
```

any idea how to do this?

Comment: You tagged it yourself: use `curses` to position your output anywhere you want.

Comment: Since you did add the curses tag, do you have any curses code you've tried?

Comment: sorry, the server needs to run on windows so i would like to do it without curses.